# WPF Button constant color when pressed

Tags: wpf, xaml

im relatively new to WPF and the styling options. What i have so far, is a menu consisting of four buttons. What i would like, is that when a button is pressed, it changes to a constant darker color (e.g dark blue) and stays that way, until another button in the menu is pressed. This is a visual aid to the user so they know which page they are on.

Currently my buttons like this

```
    <Button x:Name="CreateDog" Content="Create Dog" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,82,161,4" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="CreateDog" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="SearchDog" Grid.Column="2" Content="Search Dog" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0,82,0,4" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="SearchDog"/>
    <Button x:Name="SearchHDIndex" Grid.Column="3" Content="Search HD-Index" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="0,82,0,4" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="SearchHDIndex"/>
    <Button x:Name="BreedingPartner" Content="Breeding Partner" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Roboto" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="161,82,0,4" Command="{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" CommandParameter="BreedingPartner" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

and my app.xaml style looks like this:

```
        <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Chocolate" />
        <Setter Property = "Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SandyBrown"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chocolate"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I would use [ToggleButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/togglebutton-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) Instead... And style it like you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a scenario, it will be easier for you to use RadioButton.
ToggleButton can also be used, but then you have to embed additional logic to release the button if another one is pressed.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property = "Background" Value = "Chocolate" />
            <Setter Property = "FontSize" Value = "18" />
            <Setter Property = "FontFamily" Value = "Roboto" />
            <Setter Property = "Foreground" Value = "White" />
            <Setter Property = "FontWeight" Value = "Bold" />
            <Setter Property = "Margin" Value = "5" />
            <Setter Property = "Command" Value = "{Binding UpdateViewCommand}" />
            <Setter Property = "GroupName" Value = "menu" />
            <Setter Property = "Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SandyBrown"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chocolate"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton x:Name="CreateDog" Content="Create Dog" CommandParameter="CreateDog"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="SearchDog" Content="Search Dog" CommandParameter="SearchDog"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="SearchHDIndex" Content="Search HD-Index" CommandParameter="SearchHDIndex"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="BreedingPartner" Content="Breeding Partner" CommandParameter="BreedingPartner"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Cant describe how well this worked. I was completely unaware that radiobuttons could do this. Definitely learned something new, and i will play around with way more in the future. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

i have the answer at your question, first of I have used RadioButtons instead buttons, This is what i have got:[image]

this is the code:

```
  <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,100" Grid.RowSpan="3">         
                            <RadioButton Content="Home" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding Path=HomeViewCommand}" IsChecked="True"/>     
                            <RadioButton Content="Anagrafiche" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding Path=AnagraficheViewCommand}" IsChecked="False"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Fasi" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding Path=FasiViewCommand}"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Inventario" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding InventarioViewCommand}"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Report / Statistiche" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding Path=ReportStatisticheViewCommand}"/>
                            <RadioButton Content="Utility" Height="50" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" Command="{Binding Path=UtilityViewCommand}"/>
     </StackPanel>
```

i have created a style for the radio button so you dont need to repeat the same exact code every time:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
           x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">

                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                     
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Content="■" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFECF1FF"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Hope It Helps You!